# Sorting Multidimensional Array Without Array.Sort or DataGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created this for loop so that when I click a button, I can view the grades of fellow students that looks something like this:

```
Name    Test    Basket  Destructive   Final Grade
Alex    10      10      10            10
Danny   20      20      20            20
Dave    35      40      50            40
Goerge  0       0       0             0
Hannan  0       0       0             0
Ian     0       0       0             0
Muna    0       0       0             0
```

Here's the code for it:

```
private void uiShowMarksAZButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    uiMarksDisplayTextBox.Text = string.Join("\t", Columns);
    uiMarksDisplayTextBox.Text += System.Environment.NewLine;

    for (int i = 0; i < Names.Length; i++)
    {
        uiMarksDisplayTextBox.Text += Names[i];
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            uiMarksDisplayTextBox.Text += "\t" + Grade[i, x];
        }
        uiMarksDisplayTextBox.Text += "\t" + "\t" + FinalGrade[i];
        uiMarksDisplayTextBox.Text += System.Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to sort my table, from highest final grade, at the top, and lowest final grade at the bottom. this should not only sort the  final grade, but the name and the previous grades aswell.

I want to be able to do this without using Array.Sort and Datagrid.

Heres my attempt:

```
private void uiShowMarks100_0Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uiMarksDisplayTextBox.Text = "";
    uiMarksDisplayTextBox.Text = string.Join("\t", Columns);
    uiMarksDisplayTextBox.Text += System.Environment.NewLine;

    double temp = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < FinalGrade.Length; x++)
    {
        for (int j = x + 1; j < FinalGrade.Length; j++)
        {
            if (FinalGrade[x] > FinalGrade[j])
            {
                temp = FinalGrade[j];
                FinalGrade[j] = FinalGrade[x];
                FinalGrade[x] = temp;
            }
            uiMarksDisplayTextBox.Text += "\t" + "\t" + FinalGrade[x];
            uiMarksDisplayTextBox.Text += System.Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}
```

An example would be:

```
Name    Test    Basket  Destructive   Final Grade
Dave    35      40      50            40
Danny   20      20      20            20
Alex    10      10      10            10
Goerge  0       0       0             0
Hannan  0       0       0             0
Ian     0       0       0             0
Muna    0       0       0             0
```

Comment: The whole thing would be much (much) easier  using a Class rather than  storing the data up across multiple arrays

Comment: I know, but I'm currently restricted by what the professor wants, no easy methods!

Comment: You need to talk to your professor, welcome him to the 21st century

Comment: Hah, he wants us to understand sorting algorithms from the ground up, talking to him won't change the task requirements

Comment: understanding sorting and not grouping things up in class is totally different. He can totally teach sorting while teaching you the right way to code. I agree with Aldert that you should go tell your prof that he is doing this wrong and welcome him to the OOP century

Comment: Dismissing `Array.Sort` is not a problem, assuming that you can still use `List.Sort` or `Enumerable.OrderBy`. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to sort your data:

```
var input = new IComparable[][]
{
    new IComparable[] {"Alex",  10,      10,      10,            10},
    new IComparable[] {"Danny", 20,      20,      20,            20},
    new IComparable[] {"Dave",  35,      40,      50,            40},
    new IComparable[] {"Goerge",0 ,      0 ,      0 ,            0 },
    new IComparable[] {"Hannan",0 ,      0 ,      0 ,            0 },
    new IComparable[] {"Ian",   0 ,      0 ,      0 ,            0 },
    new IComparable[] {"Muna",  0 ,      0 ,      0 ,            0 },
};

var indexOfColumnToOrderBy = 4; // "Final Grade" field
for (var i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; ++i)
{
    for (var j = i + 1; j < input.Length; ++j)
    {
        IComparable[] t;
        if (input[i][indexOfColumnToOrderBy].CompareTo(input[j][indexOfColumnToOrderBy]) < 0)
        {
            t = input[i];
            input[i] = input[j];
            input[j] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

I've declared each item of your nested arrays as `IComparable` because both string and int implement this interface and that's why you can use method `CompareTo`

---

And that is how we do this in 21st century: create a `Student` class:

```
private class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Test { get; set; }
    public int Basket { get; set; }
    public int Destructive { get; set; }
    public int FinalGrade { get; set; }
}
```

define your input like

```
var input = new Student[]
{
    new Student {Name = "Alex",    Test = 10,  Basket = 10, Destructive = 10,   FinalGrade = 10},
    new Student {Name = "Danny",   Test = 20,  Basket = 20, Destructive = 20,   FinalGrade = 20, },
    new Student {Name = "Dave",    Test = 35,  Basket = 40, Destructive = 50,   FinalGrade = 40, },
    new Student {Name = "Goerge",  Test = 0,   Basket = 0,  Destructive = 0,    FinalGrade = 0,  },
    new Student {Name = "Hannan",  Test = 0,   Basket = 0,  Destructive = 0,    FinalGrade = 0,  },
    new Student {Name = "Ian",     Test = 0,   Basket = 0,  Destructive = 0,    FinalGrade = 0,  },
    new Student {Name = "Muna",    Test = 0,   Basket = 0,  Destructive = 0,    FinalGrade = 0,  },
};
```

And sort with Linq:

```
var sorted = input.OrderByDescending(student => student.FinalGrade).ToArray();
```

Even if this approach will not satisfy professor requirements you can use it to debug your own algorithm

Comment: How would I display this? sorry I'm barely understanding it, let alone implement it into my code.

Comment: @UnboundPhantom If we talking about console you can display initial or sorted array with a foreach loop like `foreach (var row in input) { Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",\t", row.AsEnumerable()));`. If we talking about "how to display jagged array in WinForms" -- this is a new question not related to ordering. And you can [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) that in separate thread

Answer (score 0):

For the problem as is, here is a high level algorithm:

First make sure all arrays have the same length.

Then apply your favorite sorting algorithm (I recommend bubble sort for beginner. Worst sorting algorithm but easiest to learn).

Whenever you swap the element in FinalGrade array you would swap elements in other arrays of the same index.

for example if you swapped Index 1 and 3 in FinalGrade you would also swap elements 1 and 3 for all other arrays.

I will leave the actual coding as exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can loop through it only once. You can try some recursive logic like below to keep looping until everythings sorted.

```
private List<YourObject> Sort(FinalGrade){
   bool finished = true; 
        for (int x = 0; x < FinalGrade.Length; x++)
            {
                for (int j = x + 1; j < FinalGrade.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (FinalGrade[x] > FinalGrade[j])
                    {
                        temp = FinalGrade[j];
                        FinalGrade[j] = FinalGrade[x];
                        FinalGrade[x] = temp;
                        finished = false;
                    }                      
                }
            }

   return finished? FinalGrade : Sort(FinalGrade)
}
```